# Swift View launching before data build

Tags: arrays, swift, swiftui

My Problem: I'm appending to an array that is used as parameter for my component. The component launches before anything has been appended. The array of the function gets returned before it got filled.

I have the following code:

```
struct ContentView: View {

    //This gets data from a Firebase db
    @ObservedObject var categories = getData()

    func getCards() -> [AnimatedCard] {
        var array = [AnimatedCard]()
        for i in categories.datas{
            array.append(AnimatedCard(cardContentImage: "test1", cardContentTitle: i.name, itemHeight: 300,itemWidth: 300))
        }
        return array
    }

    var body: some View {
        CarouselView(views: self.getCards())
    }
}
```

- The Firebase part is working as displaying `i.name` in a List works.
- `CarouselView` takes an Array of AnimatedCards. This is also working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:
so it appears only if data is there.

```
struct ContentView: View {

    //This gets data from a Firebase db
    @ObservedObject var categories = getData()

    func getCards() -> [AnimatedCard] {
        var array = [AnimatedCard]()
        for i in categories.datas{
            array.append(AnimatedCard(cardContentImage: "test1", cardContentTitle: i.name, itemHeight: 300,itemWidth: 300))
        }
        return array
    }

    var body: some View {
        Group {
            if self.categories.datas.count > 0 {
                CarouselView(views: self.getCards())
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You would embed condition in `body` in `Group`, otherwise it won't compile.